# get variables from record type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have record type variable new from trigger. 
Can I get variables from this record, not text representation.
Example:
`create table test(x int, y varchar);`
`insert into test values (1, 'test_var');`
if i get `new.*`
 i get this 
`(1, test_var)`
Is there an option get record like this 
`(1, 'test_var')`
Thanks.
Sorry for mistakes, english not my base language.

Comment: Probably just decompose with `SELECT * FROM NEW`.

Answer (score 0):

you should to use point notation `recordvar`.`field`. In PostgreSQL documentation is lot of [examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

```
create table test(x int, y varchar);
create or replace function trig_fx()
returns trigger as $$
begin
  raise notice '<<%>> <<%>>', new.x, new.y;
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger trig before insert on test 
  for each row execute procedure trig_fx();

postgres=# insert into test values(1, 'test var');
NOTICE:  <<1>> <<test var>>
INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is not I need.
I dont need text representation of record values. I need record with quotes in string variables.

Comment: @QweAsd I don't understand - what do you want to do? Inside record (composite type), there are not any variable - there are composite value only.